# What is the difference between the algebraic function fields and the fields itself

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm studying this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540768777) and I don't understand exactly what's the difference between the algebraic function field $F/K$ and $F$ itself.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: $F/K$ is not a field, it is a *field extension*, or else the statement that $F$ is an extension of $K$. So "an algebraic function field $F/K$" means "an algebraic function field $F$ over $K$."

Comment: @anon But what means $F/K$ being a field extension? The concept is: $F/K$ a field extension if $K$ is a subfield of the field $F$. Therefore, $F$ is a field anyway.

Comment: I would think that talking about $F/K$ as a function field seeks to convey the message that we treat $K$ as the field of constants. The underlying geometric concepts dictate this. Points will later become elements of $K^n$, or $\overline{K}^n$, or the projective space over $\overline{K}$, in other words vectors with coordinates that are algebraic over $K$. It is possible that $K$ itself is algebraically closed ($K=\Bbb{C}$ is one popular choice). In the appplications to coding theory $K$ will be a finite field, and this formulation leaves both possibilities open.

Comment: (cont'd) Given just $F$ you could not determine whether it is a function field or not. For example $F=\Bbb{C}(x,y)/\langle y^2-x^3-x\rangle$ is a function field over $K=\Bbb{C}$ or over $K=\Bbb{R}$. But it is not a function field over $K=\Bbb{Q}$, because there are infinitely many algebraically independent transcendental elements already in the subfield $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: Sure, if $F/K$ is a field extension then $F$ is a field. But that doesn't mean one would call $F/K$ a field, that's just bad English. The $/K$ part is read out loud as "over $K$," so $F/K$ in the sentence your reading is not a noun, only the $F$ part of it is. (Although when speaking of $F/K$ as an extension, one would refer to the whole thing as a noun.)

Answer (score 3):

The notation $F / K$ is just a traditional notation that indicates that $F$ is an extension of $K$, i.e. that $F$ contains $K$.  So, for now, you can regard $F / K$ as the same thing as $F$, with the notation reminding you that $F$ contains the subfield $K$.

When you start to study maps between fields, then the distinction takes on more significance.  An automorphism of a field $F$ is a bijective map $f : F \rightarrow F$ such that $f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$ and $f(xy) = f(x)f(y)$.  An automorphism of $F/K$ is an automorphism $f$ of $F$ that acts as the identity on $K$, i.e. $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in K$.  Thus all automorphisms of $F/K$ are automorphisms of $F$, but not vice versa.

As an example, there are infinitely many automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}$ (though all but the two mentioned below are "wild" and hard to describe), but there are only two automorphisms of $\mathbb{C} / \mathbb{R}$, namely the identity map and the complex conjugation map.

Comment: So, say for example $z\in F/K$ is the same to say $z\in F$?

Comment: @user42912 Would you ever write the sentence "$z$ is an element of $F$ over $K$"?

Comment: It's not proper to write $z \in F / K$, because $F/K$ really refers to the field extension (as anon pointed out in the comments), not to the field $F$.  Formally, you can think of a field extension as a pair $(F,K)$ of fields with $K \subseteq F$.

Comment: Yes, but $(F,K)$ is not fixed? So $F/K$ has only one element? the $(F,K)$?

Comment: $(F,K)$ is *not* a set.  It is a pair of sets.  So you cannot talk about an "element" of $(F,K)$.